# como puedo cargar dos FXML en una misma aplicacion simultaneamente

Tags: javafx

buenas noches quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de visualizar en una misma aplicacion 2 FXML creados con favzfx ya tengo los dos FXML creados y por aparte me funcionan adecuadamente pero no he podido integrarlos en la misma aplicacion al tiempo ya que o me funciona uno o el otro pero no ambos al tiempo.

en la imagen se ve como me gustaria que quedara mi aplicacion

de antemano agradezco su colaboracion [image: asi quedaria mi pantalla inicial con los dos FXML trabajando simultaneamente]

```js
   
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXVideo.fxml"));  // funciona para mi 
//      Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXImagen.fxml"));
 
      
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
    //   stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();
    }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root1);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
    //   stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();
    }
 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probé el siguiente codigo y abre ambos .fxml sin problemas
Suponiendo que tus controllers esten bien, esto te deberia funcionar.
Faltaria que acomodes a tu gusto las ventas acomodando las coordenandas (X,Y)

```
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXVideo.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("ventana video");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 275));
    stage.show();

    Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXImagen.fxml"));
    Scene secondScene = new Scene(root2, 300,375);
    Stage stage2 = new Stage();
    stage2.setTitle("ventana imagen");

    stage2.setX(100);
    stage2.setY(100);
    stage2.setScene(secondScene);
    stage2.show();
}
```